# Visual Studio not executing 'npm' command when starting project

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio is ignoring the execution of the  command when I start my project. I have added the necessary  elements in my project file, but it doesn't seem to work. I have verified that Node.js and npm are installed and properly configured on my system. The  variable is pointing to the correct directory, and the  file is present in that directory. I have also tried running  manually in the command line, and it works fine. Can anyone suggest possible reasons why Visual Studio is not executing the  command and provide any solutions or alternatives to resolve this issue?
`

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <SpaRoot>clientapp\</SpaRoot>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
             // This don't work
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm start" />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)build\**" />
        <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
            <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
            <!-- Changed! -->
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
            <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
        </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="6.0.16" />
</ItemGroup>
```

`

I tried to configure Visual Studio to execute three npm commands when starting my project: 'npm install', 'npm run build', and 'npm start'. I expected Visual Studio to run these commands sequentially. However, none of the commands are executed when I start the project.There are no error messages or indications of any issues in the Visual Studio output window.

Answer (score 0):

You have instructed MSBuild to run your `PublishRunWebpack` target after the `ComputeFilesToPublish` target has run. I'm not clear what "starting a project" means but the target will not be run at the start of a `build` and will not be run at the start of a `publish`.

When a `Publish` is performed, one of the earliest targets to execute is `PrepareForPublish`. You may want to try using

```xml
<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
  ...
```

You can also add a `Message` task within your `PublishRunWebpack` target that outputs a distinctive message that you can look for in the log. That will help you to understand if and when the target is executing.

```xml
<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
  <Message Text="### executing PublishRunWebpack" Importance="high" />
  ...
```